# Headings from XML after span tag

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, python-itertools

I have an XML file from which I would like to extract heading tags (h1, h2, .. as well as its text) which are between `</span>` `<span class='classy'>` tags (this way around). I want to do this in Python 2.7, and I have tried beautifulsoup and elementtree but couldn't work it out.
The file contains sections like this:

```
<section>
    <p>There is some text <span class='classy' data-id='234'></span> and there is more text now.</p> 
    <h1>A title</h1>
    <p>A paragraph</p>
    <h2>Some second title</h2>
    <p>Another paragraph with random tags like <img />, <table> or <div></p>
    <div>More random content</div>
    <h2>Other title.</h2>
    <p>Then more paragraph <span class='classy' data-id='235'></span> with other stuff.</p>
    <h2>New title</h2>
    <p>Blhablah, followed by a div like that:</p>
    <div class='classy' data-id='236'></div>
    <p>More text</p>
    <h3>A new title</h3>
</section>
```

I would like to write in a csv file like this:

```
data-id,heading.name,heading.text
234,h1,A title
234,h2,Some second title
234,h2,Another title.
235,h2,New title
236,h3,A new title
```

and ideally I would write this:

```
id,h1,h2,h3
234,A title,Some second title, 
234,A title,Another title, 
235,A title,New title, 
236,A title,New title,A new title
```

but then I guess I can always reshape it afterwards.

I have tried to iterate through the file, but I only seem to be able to keep all the text without the heading tags. Also, to make things more annoying, sometimes it is not a span but a div, which has the same class and attributes.

Any suggestion on what would be the best tool for this in Python?

I've two pieces of code that work:
- finding the text with itertools.takewhile
- finding all h1,h2,h3 but without the span id.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(xmlfile,'r'),'lxml')
spans = soup('span',{'class':'page-break'})
for el in spans:
    els = [i for i in itertools.takewhile(lambda x:x not in [el,'script'],el.next_siblings)]
    print els
```

This gives me a list of text contained between spans. I wanted to iterate through it, but there are no more html tags.

To find the h1,h2,h3 I used:

```
with open('titles.csv','wb') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    for header in soup.find_all(['h1','h2','h3']):
        if header.name == 'h1':
            h1text = header.get_text()
        elif header.name == 'h2':
            h2text = header.get_text()
        elif header.name == 'h3':
            h3text = header.get_text()
        csv_writer.writerow([h1text,h2text,h3text,header.name])
```

---

I've now tried with xpath without much luck.
Since it's an xhtml document, I used:

```
from lxml import etree
with open('myfile.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = etree.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()
spans = root.xpath('//xhtml:span',namespaces={'xhtml':'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'})
```

This gives me the list of spans objects but I don't know how to iterate between two spans.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Using a package that support xpath will be much easier.

Comment: How would I implement that? I've looked into it at some point (when I looked into elementtree), thinking it would help.. but I couldn't make it work. I thought the 'tail' of the span nodes would be helpful, but I couldn't get the headers from the tail.. Would you be able to suggest something else?